# how to serialize long to string with jackson?

Tags: string, long-integer, jackson

jackson serializes long x = 1234 to {x:1234}
For several reasons I need {x:"1234"}

any jackson annotation?

thanks.

Answer (score 35):

The following annotation could be used to serialize a long as a string:

```
@JsonSerialize(using=ToStringSerializer.class)
public long getId() {
    return id;
}
```

Comment: The other way around is `@JsonDeserialize(as = Long.class)`.